# How to drastically improve this if else if

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to improve this code from all of these else if statements to a switch or something more efficient.

```
    renderIconType = () => {
    const { icons = {} } = this.props;
    const percent = courseDataStore.getComponentCompletionPercentage(this.props.linkedNodeId);
    const isHovering = this.state.isHovering;
    const isStarted = !!courseDataStore.getComponentCompletionPercentage(this.props.linkedNodeId);
    const isCompleted = percent >= 1;
    if (isStarted && isCompleted) {
            return icons.completed
    }   else if (isStarted && isCompleted && isHovering) {
            return icons.completedHover
    }   else if (!isStarted && !isCompleted && isHovering) {
            return icons.notStartedHover
    }   else if (isStarted && !isCompleted && isHovering) {
            return icons.startedHover
    }   else if (isStarted && !isCompleted && !isHovering) {
            return icons.started
    }   else if (!isStarted && !isCompleted && !isHovering) {
            return icons.notStarted
    } 
}
```

This currently works for my intents and purposes but pains me to look at it lol.  I tried a switch statement but that doesn't work.

Comment: That looks OK to me. It's not as concise as it could be, but maintainable code isn't a golfing competition - I think any alternative would be less readable than your current (general) approach (though there are some optimizations you could make to make some of the later comparisons unnecessary). A `switch` would not help (it almost never does)

Comment: Better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com